# How to know if an Arduino restarted as a result of a WDT timeout?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I have Arduino code in which I have implemented an 8-second watchdog. To test I put a `for` loop and everything works correctly.

I want to know if it is possible to print a message when a watchdog timeout occurs in the Arduino, specifically what I want to do is send a message by XBee when a reset has occurred caused by the watch dog. I already have the XBee logic, how do I know when this reset occurs?

I already tried the solution raised here but it doesn't work for me:

[link](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=272279.0)

**My Code:**

```
#include <avr/wdt.h>
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("turning on");
  delay(1000);
  watchdogsetup();
}

void loop() {
 for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
      Serial.println();
      delay(1000);
 }  //Test to activate watchdog

       //My code ....
       //....

 wdt_reset();    // reset the watch dog to zero
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Just an idea.*

When the watchdog fires, it is uncertain if the time and resources you need to send a message via XBee are still available, so that message is probably best sent *after* the Arduino has reset and is running normally again.

I think the watchdog timer does set a flag that survives the reset itself, but it is cleared by the bootloader, so that information is lost if you use the bootloader.

So, you need to set your own flag, and read that flag back after the Arduino has reset. What you could try is writing an interrupt handler and add some other stuff to write a flag to EEPROM, something like this (untested):

```cpp
#include <EEPROM.h>
int addr = 0; // Or whatever EEPROM address you like

setup() {
  if (EEPROM.read(addr) == 1) {          //If a WDT flag was set
    // Send panicky message by XBee here
  }
  EEPROM.write(addr, 0);                 // Reset the WDT flag
  // Rest of setup() goes here
}

ISR(WDT_vect) {
  EEPROM.write(addr, 1);                 // Set the WDT flag
}
```

... and hope that the Arduino hasn't crashed beyond being able to write to the EEPROM when the watchdog fires.